# I'm would like to view this malicious payload, but am having trouble decoding it

Tags: malware, file-format, decompress, strings, byte-code

This is a gzip compressed base64 string. I tried decoding it with an online converter but it said the data was corrupt. Can anyone decode this?

```
H4sIAAAAAAAAAL1X6W6jyBb+HT8FGkWyrTg2Nl5baqnBNl7xhgGHTBQVUCxxQREovE33u98C293pm/TcHo10kZBq0Vt9Z6lTMiT3Mok8k0jYgsy9
CqPYwwFTy+Vue3hEmM/Ml3zOTgKTpMvp4NmB5DmMsPkMLCuCccz8lbtZgAj4TOF2B6JnH1sJgiUmm6SEOEoiWLy5yd1kS0kQAxs+B4B4O/jsQ+JiK6aKCo98GPawD7zg6dOnbhJFMCDne
XkACR/H0DeQB+NCkfnKaC6M4P3ceIEmYf5ibp/LA4QNgC5kxy4wXXogPrDSvSk2QXqCshwijxTyf/6ZLz7eV5/K/dcEoLiQl48xgX7ZQihfZL4VU4XrYwgLeckzIxxjm5Q1L+BqZSWzfp
YZL51tzxdz9GwRJEkUML8+YirzzFHI0+GCIsOfEcwXy6Ngh7ewcBskCJWYL4XHi0GrJCCeD+k+gREOZRjtPBPG5SEILARX0H4qzOD+isPvMhXeMlGqBYmKpYv7fsd2KXPxWVy++N76N3F
QpN+7WCjmvuU+iCoLIugAAp8Jhf5NWOVubh6zIaTnKSxw7GV8nxm2xEjUCEBwdKTT23WUwOIT85i67vHp6aL2yhmXfimoeuW68JydebbjM/OoYs96yt1kfs72041nI/GQBaOU4NeR24O2
F8DeMQC+Z16Ds/CR06CNYAZI+Uo2o4YW8pcNaPUu8ORTRB/fs/V9j3znFc7G8SZ1fEytojFR/NmYsxML+VEgQZ8CeJ7nqbNsmhLwSn1Jg+NVezqnRPkuAnFcYhYJzUmzxMgQIGiVGD6Iv
csWnxCcDfM/zJUSRDwTxOQq7qn4AaQX1V0cxCRKTOpeCsNaDqHpAZSiUmKGngWFo+w5VxPyH2LSBQh5gUMl7ahP6EqKhUzSoIms0n8HSLEsQzLyQwR9Sp1VDBEBh9aHS0pl8QYcaOX/xu
xropyzIsXqCtIbo2kAyAiTEqN6EaE1KF96F3n/0ryfS9JPdnYjePFkIUvFR+FI0oTJKM30Jvj8HcwMuohQ2MQI+wKIYbOeXhmBU/ijMvfGPP0eRgGSrPHWq4729Jfor3jcCPda1mT8Mqx
IZjdeDMQ27+2dvdme8abttcXxhtItPXbU5q3udDn0xP1wNeEtga45D17VcXhr8bLo+9PZKBaqFzlnfrNeH25YnuPqc47dWnCc0m95a+Z7+8OUjmltnU8FyseOUH/cXRlaTdQ1NKzURdfW
cCw367oFBg1k8QK2aigB6gqvh6YvVCpqk8++Q6VqbVT6g16oQWBXqtDfphvaaThWVPGVr4orMI0FnhfWysDdeHplUOmoy+bDnlIJBsVEBjx/xKOVrKDxWkECblaVZE510Czo7asCdnoSz
48CBzirJXA7GhiqgwAblarazvSDXWet+g4RXLdV6Wjinr/rH50+z/eGFdfWWWEUNJp7hF/jjbexU7kiXskilOhYsjsb4FgrleolVdvpUr27Pb+jxjUOnDLUxF4IK/Q7DStNvU/P0QuPSy
p77u7S5Smnyw9riff0dc8M2G4YKjEtFuadYOyiu3gMTXXw6ngG17bl+kl/gdGqI7oPwOWdca/bj4OkHw33jRftEECq8LjY+oYYRadqGM5IH4fcsXo6SqE0XgqqWVOPU0UMdK3Bzj1hZnB
haAwO7vSkJFKXxyr1kT7ocOZRmKtdvjZ96bdGorVQTw/s/Cgopo+2Ke/0ZCZSL3bM4KEprfuUd+sYAxTpsjDUtVlk7NkJP1u6qwNs1bGnG0kFRGN3dtclqylUJ/1hW5zo28GUqJvTxh7J
qDVFStKeKgrbi0iVtLYNcbFujQ6cqCxqD/1Dl+0aUuJ0T1YTuMLeac+FyVYP9cbrJlYro9mmOlnqu+Fr/DA79nyut1e1xesKjW2pmkwPbTNkybK9Y6dsFyKZaKdmMja3xqG396yTpDidM
QfqqLZYINfYaYjCcdtJ3CVptwOhsTer6ygA1lReTV7qm9EEDrbb5drsOfKuqxGfbTe8pZ7sdW5iP/Sx05F0pzZcBljYrF6b+xra3dUPpCff3bV2M2k8kCMFRXaro7/MZU7hwaJbxYjGoh
byNI6XNKYx/XletLA2Wa0bNMa2re05Wyy0UupBoNYcfkSnSlXH/RCM67uK6poCe8DxkDfnNMc3SJMW2LO5SoWzOOvY2Jq+6hqauzM06s0ABQ8aiqf+bGcs+SZy5q0/aDm7yWXVyUhs+3z
n/o9mRwJR7AJE6xZtWK63jYgj8dJ2UAtSjkLh46Z2C6MAItrw0ZbwWqN5hLCZNkq/6Fho23Zupp7oXaTQIVf7cFRkvhMWf3RP16VPn3R6kEvxT4txeQoDh7gl9sCxLG152EOdLeZ+//xd
HB4L36WV0q7pDZRvFaFMUTF3htolLr0nrP8z1pe7KVP9z7H+sfY3u7+FP1t6C9K7zZ8X/ok7/j1EGvAIZZXpHYzguYv8XaQuAfimZ3/jaRph9uVLn1jzhNzPaEefy3/J5UY28wah2DvRx
xV8ZdrFtE+PCYjI/Qs26Essa1cKt6DIjPob5hYw35h7CgofczX6HIucJO1dmPPr8iuzp0fJGL8yK2hC+uS4H2OD9iSQtqCp6ExISkzX/gN40eqprg4AAA==
```

Thanks.

Comment: it's not corrupted but there's a bunch of spaces here and there that prevents you from decoding it. Remove those and you should be fine.

Comment: @Pawel I'm not finding any spaces, there might be some at the end of lines but that's depending on how the text editor is sized. I even tried `cat base64string.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r" | base64 -d > dec_payload` , when opening the output, it says the archive type is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

On a linux machine

Try:

`$ cat enc_payload.txt|base64 -d > dec_payload`

Then you'll get

`$ file dec_payload 
dec_payload: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)`

Comment: When I do that it returns `base64: invalid input`

Comment: the text you provided contains some spaces you need to get rid of them first. Try  `cat enc_payload_spaces.txt | sed 's/ //g' > enc_payload`

Comment: I'm also able to reach the point as @rustamShirinov but the dec_payload file doesn't work when trying to extract compressed data